# How to reattach the decoration ring of a lens

Tags: lens, repair

## Context

So I've been using my Pentax Super Takumar 50/1.4 and I've loved it since I got it. Recently I've discovered that the decoration ring (image below) has loosened and is breaking away from the lens. Optically the lens is still good but the ring is only held in one place, rather than three. One screw also came loose (it keeps the front element to the body or so it looks like) but the rest of the screws are still good.

## Question

What's the safest way to attach the decoration ring back to the camera lens?

[image: Pentax Lens with problem]

You can see that I can fit post-its and other stuff in the gap...

Comment: What kind of connector is the remaining attachment point? Screw? Platic tab? etc.?

Comment: @MichaelClark. It's held by, from what I can tell metal and glue I assume. There's some yellow residual where the other two sides are at.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I've solved my problem with super glue. My friend told me super glue works best between metals and it's holding it down just fine. I first grinded away the yellow powder and related where it was held, giving the glue a clean surface for the glue to bind on.

Word of caution I was ok throwing the lens/selling it for parts if it didn't work out.